# asp.net json string to de-serialize into varibales

Tags: asp.net, json

I'm new to json and I need help with following json string, I need to fetch values into string variables to save into db.

```
{
"message_id": {"8624389": "447123456789"},
"sent_text": "Test message",
"parts_count": 1
}
```

how can I get values of message_id, sent_text and parts_count into variables?

Thanks

Comment: What are you using for JSON? What version of .Net?

Comment: There are many ways to deal with serialization and deserialization in .Net, one being the DataContract class which is probably one of the older ways, my suggestion is if you are not using any outside dependencies from .Net, I would use System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavascriptSerializer class object and then make a custom class type that has properties to match your JSON string. So you would have a custom class with a property of Array of Integers named message_id, another property of type string called sent_text, and a third property of type integer called parts_count, then you can use

Comment: version .net 4.5 json string i get from API response

Comment: continued from last comment, the javascriptserializer object to deserialize the JSON string into your custom class object type by using Deserialize() with two parameters, first being your JSON string, second being the object type you expect it to return, documentation here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191864(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Or you can use JSON.NET, which is what Microsoft uses by default in the MVC and Web API frameworks. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: this json says the message_id is another object.  is that correct?

Comment: Well yes you're correct that it's an object, but whether that's "correct" as per your requirements / expectation / specification, how can we know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this website:https://app.quicktype.io/
It uses  newtonsoft nuget package. With a little tweaking it saves alot of time.

```
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
    //
    //    using MyNamespace;
    //
    //    var myObject = MyObject.FromJson(jsonString);

    namespace MyNamespace
    {
        using System;
        using System.Net;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        using Newtonsoft.Json;

        public partial class MyObject
        {
            [JsonProperty("message_id")]
            public MessageId MessageId { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("sent_text")]
            public string SentText { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("parts_count")]
            public long PartsCount { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class MessageId
        {
            [JsonProperty("8624389")]
            public string The8624389 { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class MyObject
        {
            public static MyObject FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json, MyNamespace.Converter.Settings);
        }

        public static class Serialize
        {
            public static string ToJson(this MyObject self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, MyNamespace.Converter.Settings);
        }

        public class Converter
        {
            public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
                DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            };
        }
    }
```